# How can I mimic GChat's scrollable area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

GChat keeps the textarea scrolled to the end when new text appears, however if the user scrolls away from the end, it waits until you've scrolled back down to continue this behavior.

Using just HTML, Javascript and JQuery, how could one mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you add data, execute something like:

```
this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
```

This is just standard Javascript that forces you to scroll to the bottom.  To only force someone to stay scrolled to the bottom when they're already at the bottom, do something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElementName');
var atBottom = (elem.scrollTop >= (elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight));
// add your text updates here
if(atBottom) elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/xjmha/4/

(Ignore the other versions of the fiddle... I was failing with jQuery.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Guttsy. But how would you compare against that if user moves the scrollable (to stop autscrolling)? To say somehting like" if scrollbar size = someN and scroll is not at that someN then dont autoscroll.

Comment: I'm working on it... turns out it's a bit more of a challenge than expected. Probably some mundane detail I'm missing.

Comment: Yeah its a bit trickier then you'd think. At least at my skill level it has proven to be

Comment: The link in my answer has a "working" version. I'm having problems with accessing the attributes in jQuery, so that's why it's a bit sloppy. Is jQuery necessary for this? Not exactly.

Comment: what is the point? just stop the event when "onmouseover"ing the textarea and start it again on "onmouseout"?

Comment: @Walialu Your mouse might not necessarily be on the item as you're reading it and scrolling.

Comment: @Guttsy then use onfocus (when the textfield receives focus) and onblur (when the textfield lost focus) too ;)

Comment: @Walialu Then post your idea as an answer :) I think my solution is quite straightforward. My problems were with jQuery and jQuery alone. Just a tad rusty.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    height: 80px;
    width: 450px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function(){
    var t = document.getElementById('foo');
    if(t['data-scrollinglocked'])return;
    var h = t.scrollHeight;
    t.scrollTop = h;
}

var moo = function(){
    var t = document.getElementById('foo');
t.innerHTML = t.innerHTML + new Date()+"\n";
}

var init = function(){
    // global scope ;)
    mooInterval = setInterval("moo()",1000);
    fooInterval = setInterval("foo()",500);

    var t = document.getElementById('foo');
    t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 0;
    t.onmouseout = function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 0;
    };
    t.onmouseover = function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 1;
    };
    t.onclick = function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 1;
    };
    t.onblur = function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 1;
    };
    t.onfocus = function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 1;
    };
    t.onblur= function(){
        t['data-scrollinglocked'] = 0;
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foo"></div>
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<script>init();</script>
</body>

</html>
```